# Problem to use a Map in Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get the length of a Map and I keep getting "undefined". Could please someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

This is the part of the code that gives me problems.

```
const GYMdetail: { [key: string]: number} = {};
GYMdetail[`${doc.data().name} (${doc.data().personalID})`] = 650;
const subtotal = 650 * GYMdetail.size;
```

This is the complete function code

```
export const addGymMonthlyExpense =
  functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const query1 = admin.firestore().collection("users");
    const query = query1.where("subscriptions.gym.active", "==", true);
    query.get()
        .then(async (allUsers) => {
          allUsers.docs.forEach(async (doc) => {
            if (doc != undefined) {
              const houseForGym = doc.data().subscriptions.gym.house;
              await admin.firestore()
                  .doc(`houses/${houseForGym}/expenses/2022-04`)
                  .get().then((snapshot) => {
                    if (snapshot.data() == undefined) {
                      console.log(`${houseForGym}-${doc.data().name}: CREAR!!`);
                    } else if (snapshot.data()!.issued == false) {

                      let detail: { [key: string]: any} = {};
                      const GYMdetail: { [key: string]: number} = {};
                      detail = snapshot.data()!.detail;
                      GYMdetail[
                          `${doc.data().name} (${doc.data().personalID})`
                      ] = 650;
                      const subtotal = 650 * GYMdetail.size;
                      
                      detail["GYM"] = {"total": subtotal, "detail": GYMdetail};
                      snapshot.ref.set({"detail": detail}, {merge: true});
                    }
                    return null;
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(
                        `${houseForGym} - ${doc.data().name}: ${error}`);
                    response.status(500).send(error);
                    return null;
                  });
            }
          });
          response.send("i");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          response.status(500).send(error);
        });
  });
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you need the size of the map? What exactly is in this map and what exactly do you want to know about it in this function?

Comment: I wanted to know how many items were there in the map. Finally I got it with:
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(GYMdetail).length;

Comment: Honestly this is so dumb why it can't just do map.size. Thought I was going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Since you are executing an asynchronous call to the database in your code, you need to return a promise from the top-level code; otherwise Cloud Functions may kill the container when the final `}` executes and by that time the database load won't be done yet.

So:

```
export const addGymMonthlyExpense =
  functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const query1 = admin.firestore().collection("users");
    const query = query1.where("subscriptions.gym.active", "==", true);
    return query.get()
      ...
```

Next you'll need to ensure that all the nested `get()` calls also get a chance to finish before the Functions container gets terminated. For that I recommend not using `await` for each nested `get` call, but a single `Promise.all` for all of them:

```
query.get()
    .then(async (allUsers) => {
      const promises = [];
      allUsers.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const houseForGym = doc.data().subscriptions.gym.house;
        promises.push(admin.firestore()
          .doc(`houses/${houseForGym}/expenses/2022-04`)
          .get().then((snapshot) => {
            ...
          });
      });
      response.send("i");
      return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      response.status(500).send(error);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just took your suggestion and updated my code and tested it. I know it is was sloppy before, but still now I cannot get the size of the Map GYMdetail.

Any idea on how to get that value?

Comment: The fraction of the code that gives me problems is in the first code section right under the title: "This is the part of the code that gives me problems."

Additionally I added the full function just in case I am missing something important that might be of use for whomever is analysing the issue.